# Regexp text matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the following string fromat and breakdown into an array

```
var str = "A123456 some text F unwaned text blabla A123457 another text string F";
```

into something like this

```
["A123456 some text F", "A123457 another text string F"]
```

Comment: What rule applies to split? (From `A` to `F` ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "A123456 some text F unwaned text blabla A123457 another text string F";
str.match(/A.*?F/g)
// => ["A123456 some text F", "A123457 another text string F"]
```

Comment: @IuthisaamMuhammadSaeed, It would be better to clearly state what rule apply to split the string in the question.